# Saturation of a submodule

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $R$ be an integral domain, $M$ a left $R$-module and $N$ a $R$-submodule of $M$. What is the definition of $\operatorname{sat}_M(N)$?

Comment: An aside: Integral domains are commutative, so there  is no reason to distinguish between left- and right-modules, you can just take $R-$modules.

Answer (score 0):

Let $S$ be some multiplicative closed subset in $R$. Then $\text{sat}_S(N)$ is defined usually as the set of $m \in M$ such that there is an $s \in S$ with $sm \in N$. This is called the $S$-saturation of $N$ in $M$.

Possibly this is what you're looking for?

Comment: Isn't that all $M$ since $0\cdot m\in N?$ I think you need $r\neq 0,$ at least?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Correct. I made an edit.